# Cancel Game Center Multiplayer invites when in game

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, game-center

Hello I am currently trying to find a way to cancel invites when a player is already in a 1v1 game.

Scenario: A and B are in a game, C invites A to play a game.

What is happening now, the banner still pops up saying C is requesting A to play a game.

What I need is to either disable the invite altogether, or if A accepts the invite, I need A to tell C that the invite can not be completed, so that C is not sitting and waiting for a request.

I am using the GKInviteEventListener delegate and checking on didAcceptInvite for when the invite was accepted.

The code or methods can either be in ObjC or Swift.  Thank you.